# Ajax 301 Redirect

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess, redirect

I am calling Ajax inside my admin of php application. Basically my URL is
**www.mysite.com/admin/product/search/**
upon clicking a button my ajax should call PHP from other file in Same folder but I get 301 permanent on Network console Chrome. Upon clicking it should be:
**www.mysite.com/admin/product/file.php/**

but it is **www.mysite.com/admin/product/search/file.php**/ which is giving 301

here is my code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){

           $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'file.php',
                success: function(data) {
                   console.log(data);
                   

                }
            });
   });
});
</script>
```

I have tried '/file.php' , /../file.php but nothing is working.

my .htaccess I think it is creating a problem also I want to add .php extension but when I remove last line it gives me 404 page error

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_gzip.c>
    mod_gzip_on       Yes
    mod_gzip_dechunk  Yes
    mod_gzip_item_include file      \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl|jpg|png|gif)$
    mod_gzip_item_include handler   ^cgi-script$
    mod_gzip_item_include mime      ^text/.*
    mod_gzip_item_include mime      ^application/x-javascript.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude mime      ^image/.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</IfModule>
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /app/admin/
RewriteRule ^styles/(.+)?$ templates/styles/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^scripts/(.+)?$ templates/scripts/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^icons/(.+)?$ templates/icons/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^images/(.+)?$ templates/images/$1 [L]

# Removed Redirect Loop #1518
#RewriteRule ^ajax/(.+)?$ ajax/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?q=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL should be:

```
url: '../file.php'
```

`..` means to go up one level in the directory hierarchy.

I'm not sure why you're getting a 301 code, you should be getting 404 for a file not found.

Comment: getting 200 now but on console.log it is showing empty line. something is working but not getting desired JSON

Comment: added dataType:json but now on console.log it says null

Comment: Maybe the script requires parameters to be sent with the `data:` option?

Comment: working fine on seperate but inside my application it is giving error can you check my .htaccess I have added above